# How to turn raster of RGB points to elevation map?

Tags: qgis, 3d

I have a 2d RGB raster image
[image]
It has points with RGB in each point, Black background. It is a form of a depth map.

I want to turn it into elevation points: turn RGB data from channels into XYZ data. I know minimal and maximal X, Y, Z values mapped to non zero RGB points. How to do such raster with channels into points with XYZ mapping in QGIS 3.20?

Comment: Can you add an example how RGB values should be converted into Z values? You want to use all three bands - or just one? Can you provide sample data?

Comment: All three  R== X, G==Y, B==Z.

Comment: R=X and G=Y??? Don't understand: the raster is not georeferenced and you want to create a georeferenced raster from the RG values and add elevation from B?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Raster calculator to extract a band from the RGB image. Simply open `Menu Raster / Raster calculator`, then select the band you want and run (see screenshot). This creates a black/white image with the values from the selected band, thus in your case a Digital Elevation Model.

[image]